# Oracle SQL subtracting between subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries, the first is this:

```
SELECT * FROM "HOTELS"
LEFT JOIN "ROOM" ON "HOTELS"."HOTEL_ID"="ROOM"."HOTEL_ID" 
LEFT JOIN "ROOM_TYPE" ON "ROOM"."ROOM_T"="ROOM_TYPE"."ROOM_T"
WHERE ("ROOM_TYPE"."ROOM_T"='Two beds' AND "HOTELS"."NAME"='Sunset Hotel');
```

The second is this:

```
SELECT * FROM "HOTELS"
LEFT JOIN "RESERVATIONS" ON "HOTELS"."HOTEL_ID"="RESERVATIONS"."HOTEL_ID" 
WHERE ("HOTELS"."NAME"='Sunset Hotel' AND "RESERVATIONS"."DATE"='7/20/2016');
```

(I translated the strings from my native language)

OK, I am running the first one in Oracle's APEX SQL Commands page and it returns 4 entries, which are the rooms I am interested in.

I am running the second and it returns the reserved rooms for the date I am interested in, 1 row result.

**Now I want to do the subtraction so that I get left with only the 3 rooms that are not reserved at that date.**

But I try different formats that I found after googling and I always get some useless error messages.

Comment: Unrelated, but: all those double quotes (`"`) are unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `left join` and check for o matches:

```
SELECT *
FROM "HOTELS" h JOIN
     "ROOM" r
     ON h."HOTEL_ID" = r."HOTEL_ID" JOIN
     "ROOM_TYPE" rt
     ON r."ROOM_T" = rt."ROOM_T" LEFT JOIN
     "RESERVATIONS" r
     ON h."HOTEL_ID" r."HOTEL_ID" AND r."DATE" = '7/20/2016'
WHERE h."NAME= 'Sunset Hotel' AND
      rt."ROOM_T"='Two beds' AND
      r."HOTEL_ID" IS NULL;
```

You should not need `LEFT JOIN` for the hotels/rooms/room type connections.  The ids should be valid -- and even if they are not, the check on room type requires matches anyway.  The `LEFT JOIN` is needed for `RESERVATIONS`.

Comment: I don't understand why all the answers have a "IS NULL" expression at the end. The hotel id is never NULL. Maybe I screwed up explaining the schema or while renaming the variables...

Can't I just subtract one query from another, since I at least have them working separately?

Comment: @vga1232 . . . The `IS NULL` is selecting rows that have no matching reservation.  It is often used with `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to include the `RESERVATIONS` table and put the date filter as part of the join condition (the other tables can use `INNER JOIN`s):

```
SELECT *
FROM   "HOTELS" h
        INNER JOIN "ROOM" r
        ON h."HOTEL_ID" = r."HOTEL_ID" 
        INNER JOIN "ROOM_TYPE" t
        ON r."ROOM_T" = t."ROOM_T"
        LEFT JOIN "RESERVATIONS" v
        ON ( h."HOTEL_ID" = v."HOTEL_ID" AND v."DATE"= DATE '2016-07-20' )
WHERE   t."ROOM_T"   = 'Two beds'
AND     h."NAME"     = 'Sunset Hotel'
AND     v."HOTEL_ID" IS NULL;
```

Then to test for a non-reservation you can check that the `RESERVATIONS` primary key is `NULL` (as per the last line).

Also note, that if you are comparing to a `DATE` data type then if you are using a string value Oracle will do an implicit `TO_DATE()` using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter as the format mask - if this does not match then it will throw exceptions and if it does work and then the parameter gets changed it will break the query. It would be better to use a date literal value instead (e.g. `DATE '2016-07-20'`).

Finally, you probably don't need to use double quotes around all the table and column names. By default, Oracle will convert column and table names to upper-case (which is what you are using so this isn't an issue) and the only reason to double-quote identifiers is if you want to specify a case-sensitive format (which you should try to avoid) or if you want to use keywords as names (which you also ought to avoid). So, if possible change the `RESERVATIONS.DATE` column to another name as `DATE` is a keyword in oracle (but the rest of the column names should not need quotes).

Comment: I run this but it returns no results. If I remove the final line then it returns 4 rows that show reserved rooms, all of them on that specific date, even though some of the entries don't exist in the Reservations table, at least on that date. Is there a mistaken join going on?

Answer (score 0):

> I always get some useless error messages

Error messages are never useless, in fact they are very useful to understand what's wrong your are doing or asking your RDBMS to do.

> "RESERVATIONS"."DATE"='7/20/2016'

This is wrong since you are comparing a **DATE** with a **string** literal. Always, explicitly convert the string into date using **TO_DATE** and proper format mask. Or, if you dealing only with the date part and not concerned with the time portion, then use the **ANSI date literal** which uses a fixed format `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`

Coming back to your original requirement about the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM "HOTELS" h
LEFT JOIN "ROOM" r
ON h."HOTEL_ID" = r."HOTEL_ID"
LEFT JOIN "ROOM_TYPE" t
ON r."ROOM_T" = t."ROOM_T"
LEFT JOIN "RESERVATIONS" v
ON ( h."HOTEL_ID" = v."HOTEL_ID"
AND v."DATE"      = TO_DATE('2016-07-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
WHERE t."ROOM_T"  = 'Two beds'
AND h."NAME"      = 'Sunset Hotel'
AND v."HOTEL_ID" IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you, I am following the DATE advice from now on. Your answer is like the other one I commented on, it returns no data, I don't understand the check against the NULL id. The id is never NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use MINUS:

```
Subquery1 
MINUS 
Subquery2
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm